# AngularJS IE8 Include

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having some issues with Angular includes and HTML 5 shimming.

I've got a header, like so:

`<header data-ng-include data-src="'partials/header.html'"></header>`

Inside the header.html I have:

`<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
</nav>`

It renders OK in IE8. But any styles for `nav > ul` don't get applied. If I change my CSS to `div > ul` it works. Or if I change the `<nav>` to a `<div>` it works too!

I figured it was a HTML 5 shimming issue, so made sure I have my shim in place (even tried adding the manual element create shim into the head):

`<!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="/js/vendor/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->`

But it doesn't help with the styles. If I move the code out of the `ng-include` and include it inline, it works fine... Any ideas?

Here's a [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yu7A58JKil8c0PYx4J0h?p=catalogue)

**NOTE: IE8 doesn't work with Plnkr - but you can download the source to test locally.**

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is a bug in Angular with HTML5 tags and directives.

[here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1381)